# Заполнить содержимое div по высоте до значения max-height

Tags: css

Помогите сообразить.

Есть контейнер, внутри которого три элемента `list-item`.
Нужно заполнить `list-item` его содержимым по высоте таким образом, чтобы высота `list-item` заполнилась до значения `max-height: 512px`.

Иначе говоря, нужно чтобы `list-item` сохранял пропорции при масштабировании, исходя из начальных `384х512`, а его содержимое заполняло всю область.

Пробовал через `padding-bottom: 128.65%` для элемента `top`, всё в принципе отлично, но только с фиксированным кол-вом элементов, а это не мой случай.

```css
.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.list-item {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 512px;
}

.item-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.top {}

.mid {}

.bot {}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="item-content">
      <div class="top">TOP</div>
      <div class="bot">BOTTOM</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="item-content">
      <div class="top">TOP</div>
      <div class="mid">MIDDLE</div>
      <div class="bot">BOTTOM</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="item-content">
      <div class="top">TOP</div>
      <div class="bot">BOTTOM</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Забыли задать высоту для `.item-content`

```
.item-content {
  height: 100%;
  // other properties
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, лучшим решением в моём случае будет присвоить родителю `list-item` `position: relative; padding-top: 66.67%`, а потомку `item-content` `position: absolute; height: 100%`?